# Ansible execute a command shell bash to docker container or volume

Tags: bash, docker, ansible, kapacitor

I pretend to execute a bash file inside a docker container with ansible. The firts task its sucess.

My task:

```
- name: Copy tickscripts
  copy:
    src: /home/debian/github/tick_playbook/roles/alertas
    dest: /var/lib/docker/volumes/kapacitor_storage/_data/

- name: Execute tickscripts
  shell: bash /var/lib/docker/volumes/kapacitor_storage/_data/alertas/run_alertas.sh
```

Container name: tick_kapacitor
volume container: kapaciotr_sotage

Run playbook and 1 task is ok

```
root@teste:/# cat /var/lib/docker/volumes/kapacitor_storage/_data/alertas/

 run_alertas.sh  tasks/          tickscripts/

root@teste:/# cat /var/lib/docker/volumes/kapacitor_storage/_data/alertas/
```

#

I try also:

```
  - name: Execute tickscripts
  shell: docker exec -ti tick_kapacitor /bin/bash var/lib/kapacitor/alertas/run_alertas.sh
```

Resp:

```
TASK [alertas : Execute tickscripts] *******************************************
fatal: [192.168.85.79]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "docker exec -ti tick_kapacitor /bin/bash var/lib/kapacitor/alertas/run_alertas.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.043861", "end": "2019-03-18 17:52:50.542327", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2019-03-18 17:52:50.498466", "stderr": "the input device is not a TTY", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/debian/github/tick_playbook/teste.retry
```

i go to the machine and put

```
  docker exec -ti tick_kapacitor /bin/bash var/lib/kapacitor/alertas/run_alertas.sh
```

Resp:

```
var/lib/kapacitor/alertas/tickscripts/cpu99_alert_stream.tick
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `-ti` flag from your shell command.

It is used for starting a persistent, interactive session - neither of which you are interested in while running an Ansible play.